# Simple array mapping in Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following JSON coming back from a web service which I am trying to bind to a simple list just to show the name and image for customers:

```
{"Customers":{"data":[{"CustomerID":1,"CustomerName":"Jones","CustomerImage":"~/Images/Customers/Jones02.gif","CustomerEnabled":true},{"CustomerID":7,"CustomerName":"Hughes","CustomerImage":"~/Images/Customers/Hughes057847.gif","CustomerEnabled":true},{"CustomerID":13,"CustomerName":"Michaels","CustomerImage":"~/Images/Customers/M12012.gif","CustomerEnabled":true},{"CustomerID":123,"CustomerName":"Bernard","CustomerImage":"~/Images/Customers/kb040412.gif","CustomerEnabled":true}]}}
```

In my markup I have

```
<section id="CustomerList">
    <ul data-bind: 'foreach: data'>
        Data: <span data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></span>

        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:CustomerID"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

But I cannot get it to write out the ID's via knockout's databinding.

My JS to execute this process is simply:

```
var ViewModel = {
    Customer: []
};
dataService.getCustomers(function (data) {
    ViewModel.Customer = data.Customers;
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
});
```

I can step into the getCustomers() callback and validate the JSON is coming back as above, and I can also query ViewModel.Customer and see the data assigned, but nothing gets written out.
I assumed this would be trivial, but nothing has worked thus far.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

```
<section id="CustomerList">
    <ul data-bind: 'foreach: data'>
        Data: <span data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></span>

        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:CustomerID"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Change:

```
<ul data-bind: 'foreach: data'>
```

To:

```
<ul data-bind: 'foreach: Customer>
```

And in:

```
dataService.getCustomers(function (data) {
    ViewModel.Customer = data.Customers;
    ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
});
```

Change:

```
ViewModel.Customer = data.Customers;
```

To:

```
ViewModel.Customer = data.Customers.data;
```

Finally you need to remove the debug line with the data from within the `<ul>` as this is invalidating the markup.

Working sample can be viewed at http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/35eQQ/2/

Comment: If I change it to that is gives me: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings. Message: ReferenceError: CustomerID is not defined; Bindings value: text:CustomerID

Comment: Thanks, but the same result. $data is rendering the entire JSON structure in the first span, but the individual items aren't rendering when bound and I still get the error.

Comment: Updated my answer with a jsFiddle. I think the debug line within your <ul> was invalidating the markup. This should now work. See http://jsfiddle.net/unklefolk/35eQQ/2/

Comment: Thanks - I think you are right. Its working now using the same approach as the JSFiddle above. Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the binding should look something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: Customer.data">
    Data: <span data-bind="text: JSON.stringify(ko.toJS($data), null, 2)"></span>

    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: CustomerID"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Since the only bindable property in your viewmodel is `Customer`.

Even if that works, you might want to introduce an observable array with the customers so that you can enable two way bindings as well. Then you can also use filtering and what not. Just fill the observable array like this:

```
dataService.getCustomers(function (data) {
   ViewModel.MyCustomerObservableArray(data.Customers.data);
   ko.applyBindings(ViewModel);
});
```

Comment: If I change it to that is gives me: Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: CustomerID is not defined;
Bindings value: text:CustomerID

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clear..can you post exactly what you are doing?...there are few things

1. Customer property needs to be an oberservablearray
2. Also you need to first convert your json into JS object by using 
   ko.mapping.fromJSON(serverdata,  MappingOptions, viewModel). You
   then dont need to stringify on the fly.
3. Your server data needs to be properly mapped with your viewmodel
   properties. Your object in the array has several keys, however in
   your view you have not mentioned remaining 'key' properties. For
   that you need to use knockoutjs `ignore`.

You can see how mapping works at [Knockout website](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)